# GCP bucket to vm instance of different organization

Tags: google-cloud-platform, instance, data-transfer, bucket

what would be the correct procedure to copy a directory from a bucket in organization_1 to a VM instance in organization_2?

John's comment made me realize that I was using to different ssh-id, so I will have to correct that first. I am using MobaXterm.

Armando at the moment I am testing from a company bucket to a VM, created on a different project, which I created using the free trial.

I hope it makes sense, I am very new on cloud technology.

Comment: The credentials you are using must have permissions to both buckets. This means adding your identity or the service account identity to both organizations under IAM at the ORG, Folder, or Project level. Edit your question with details on the identity you are using (user or service account) and the software/tool performing the copy.

Comment: Hi Fabio, I hope you are doing amazing. [qq] are you using VPC-SC? Are there any IAM policy that prevents you to add a SA from another ORG to yours?

Comment: Set the correct permission on the bucket for the service account of the compute engine, and then use gsutil to download the files. What are your blockers or questions on that?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thanks, so in any case organization 2 needs to have a bucket? at the moment i am learning/testing using my gmail account, I created a VM there, guess I will need to have a bucket there as well and then work on the permission.

Comment: Depends on where you want to put the files. You told: copy directory from a bucket to a VM. Therefore, to store files on a VM, only the permission of the VM service account to acccess in read mode to the bucket is enough.

Comment: Thanks to all contributors I hope the following line will help others "gcloud compute scp --project=project-id  --zone=instance-zone --recurse dir ssh_user@instance-ID:/home/ssh_user/dir"